# how to add slides to bootstrap carousel

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'd like to add slides to a bootstrap carousel that are received from a REST service.

I've tried to add angular directives such as ngFor in the component's HTML. Can't figoure out how to control the "active" flag for the first slide from the array list.

I know how to add statics slides by creating "carousel-items" from which the first must be declared as "active":

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/800x300">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/800x300">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>second slide label</h5>
        <p>second slide text</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/800x300">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>third slide label</h5>
        <p>third slide text</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel"
   role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel"
   role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance - this is what I tried so far to control the "active" flag:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div *ngFor="let teaser of hashtagsTeaser; let isFirst = first" class="carousel-item [class.active]="isFirst">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/800x300">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel"
   role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel"
   role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: in *ngFor you can add let first=first, see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables, and use [class]="first?'active':null"

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to the *ngFor

```
*ngFor="let teaser of hashtagsTeaser; let isFirst = first 
[class.active]="isFirst"
```

this will add the active class to the first slide

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this syntax. It raises a parsing error when I add something like <div *ngFor="let teaser of hashtagsTeaser; let isFirst = first" class="carousel-item [class.active]="isFirst">

Comment: can you share the detail code as well as the error so I might be able to help you . also don't use ngFor and NgIf as they won't work on one div elements

Comment: Thanks a lot, please see the edited question above.